# Query Joining on Column headings

Tags: sql-server-2016, pivot

I have Survey results given to me in a massive table. (300+ columns)

A list of questions is provided in a table, and the Survey results in another.

Questions.

```
+-----+-----+---------------------------------+
| idx | QID |              QDesc              |
+-----+-----+---------------------------------+
|   1 | Q1  | Are you alive?                  |
|   2 | Q2  | Do you like pizza?              |
|   3 | Q3  | Do you like pineapple on pizza? |
+-----+-----+---------------------------------+
```

The answers from each person surveyed are entered on 1 line, each question/answer in it's own column.

```
+-----+----+-----+-----+
| idx | Q1 | Q2  | Q3  |
+-----+----+-----+-----+
|   1 |  1 | Yes | No  |
|   2 |  0 | No  | No  |
|   3 |  1 | Yes | Yes |
+-----+----+-----+-----+
```

I want to create a view on this which will be used in Excel Pivot tables. So I want the quest text in each row. Something like:

```
+-----+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------+
| idx |     Q1Desc     | Q1Result |       Q2Desc       | Q2Result |             Q3Desc              | Q3Result |
+-----+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------+
|   1 | Are you alive? |        1 | Do you like pizza? | Yes      | Do you like pineapple on pizza? | No       |
|   2 | Are you alive? |        0 | Do you like pizza? | No       | Do you like pineapple on pizza? | No       |
|   3 | Are you alive? |        1 | Do you like pizza? | Yes      | Do you like pineapple on pizza? | Yes      |
+-----+----------------+----------+--------------------+----------+---------------------------------+----------+
```

I feel like the answer should be a unpivot/pivot, but the thought is making my head explode. Over time i'll be loading more results and the questions and result columns could be added to, so i want it to be dynamic.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.idx 
     , q1.qdesc q1desc, a.q1 q1result
     , q2.qdesc q2desc, a.q2 q2result 
     , q3.qdesc q3desc, a.q3 q3result
     , ...
FROM answers a
   , questions q1
   , questions q2 
   , questions q3
   , ...
WHERE q1.qid=1 
  AND q2.qid=2 
  AND q3.qid=3 
  AND ...
```

The number of questions/answers is dynamic, so use dynamic SQL for to build the query text.

PS. Do you really want to output the result table which contains **600** columns?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes it works, but would still still to be updated/edited  as columns are added. Re 600 Columns: Ideally not, but the idea is to create a view to feed multiple pivot tables. Users would be able to edit thier queries to cherry pick which fields they want.

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot *would still still to be updated/edited as columns are added.* Read one more time: *use dynamic SQL for to build the query text*. I.e. obtain fields list, build query text using common string manipulation operators into a variable, then EXEC this query.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I would suggest to use CASE statement plus MAX function

Below works for me:

```
;WITH Question AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS idx, 'Q1' AS QID, 'Are you alive?' AS QDesc UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS idx, 'Q2' AS QID, 'Do you like pizza?' AS QDesc UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS idx, 'Q3' AS QID, 'Do you like pineapple on pizza?' AS QDesc
), Answer AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS idx, '1' AS Q1, 'Yes' AS Q2, 'No' AS Q3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS idx, '0' AS Q1, 'No'  AS Q2, 'No' AS Q3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS idx, '1' AS Q1, 'Yes' AS Q2, 'Yes' AS Q3
)
SELECT      a.Idx,
            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QID = 'Q1' THEN q.QDesc END) AS Q1Desc,
            MAX(a.Q1) AS Q1Answer,
            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QID = 'Q2' THEN q.QDesc END) AS Q2Desc,
            MAX(a.Q2) AS Q2Answer,
            MAX(CASE WHEN q.QID = 'Q3' THEN q.QDesc END) AS Q3Desc,
            MAX(a.Q3) AS Q3Answer
FROM        Answer a
CROSS JOIN  Question q
GROUP BY    a.Idx
```

Comment: I like the idea of the CTE, but the CASE is still hardcoded. meaning the view would need to be edited each time columns are added.

Comment: so, in that case, you'll need to build dynamic queries though.